# Unable to build ionic app in production, stuck with node module errors

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, npm

I am working on an ionic app and when doing **ionic cordova build ios --prod**
This is working fine without --prod flag.

Try to build an ionic app with --prod flag but got this error -

[image]

> Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined

this is my package.json content here -

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3"
    "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.7",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.4",
    "@types/node": "^9.3.0",
    "codecov": "^3.0.0",
    "ionic": "3.20.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.9.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "npm-install-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^4.1.1",
    "typescript": "^2.9.1",
    "ws": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.6"
  }
```

I tried **npm install** and updated typescript and @angular/cli but no luck.

Comment: Try removing node modules using `rm -rf node_modules` and reinstalling the dependecies using `npm install`

Comment: What i remember, you cant build ios app with build command, you need mac os  and xcode

Comment: Please copy paste stack trace as text and dont add images of it

Comment: When I install typescript@2.4.2 this error went but now this is happening -  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7616